# running a while loop in the background of a tkinter application

Tags: python, tkinter

I  am trying to run a loop that checks to see if a card has been scanned and if one has been scanned and is valid then switch to another screen. however, if I run a while loop the program crashes and if i use .after then i get a recursion error. i tried to limit how often the .after runs but it still crashes. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import PIL
import serial

def MainScreen():
    global mainscreen
    mainscreen = Tk()
    mainscreen.title('Main Screen')
    mainscreen.geometry('400x400')

    backgroundImage = PhotoImage(file="waves2.png")
    backgroundLabel = Label(mainscreen, image=backgroundImage)

    backgroundLabel.pack()
    mainscreen.after(10000, Scan())
    mainscreen.mainloop()

def Scan():
    x = ""
    if ser.in_waiting > 0:
        line = ser.readline().decode('utf-8').rstrip()
        x = line.strip()
        print(x)
        if x != '':
            print("card accepted")
        else:
            print('scan card')
     mainscreen.update()
     mainscreen.after(10000, Scan())

 if __name__ == '__main__':
        ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
        ser.flush()
```

MainScreen()

Comment: Did you mean `mainscreen.after(10000, Scan)`?

Comment: The answer to Ted's question is "yes, that is what you meant."  What you are doing calls `Scan` immediately, then passes its return value (`None`) to `after.  You want to pass the function, not call the function.

Answer (score 0):

Running loop in different thread might be the answer

```
from tkinter import *
import threading
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x700")
run = False

def Scan():
   global run
   run = True
   while run:
       you code here

function = threading.Thread(target=Scan)
function.start()

root.mainloop()
run = False
```

Comment: There is missing closing double quote in `root.geometry(...)`.  Also you need to declare `run` as global inside `Scan()`, otherwise a local variable `run` will be created instead and `run = False` at the end will not terminate the thread.

Comment: That was so messed up. Thanks for noticing that